# How to find all elements of the same type with python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

source = requests.get("https://www.11v11.com/teams/arsenal/tab/opposingTeams/opposition/Chelsea/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
games = soup.find(class_="result-status")
print(games.text)
```

This certain code only finds one result-status element. Meanwhile, I need hundreds.

The output I'm looking for would be something like "L, W, L, D" depending on the data of the website of course. I imported CSV because in the end I need it in that format.

Comment: did You try: `soup.find_all(class_='result-status')`, that should return a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `.find()` it will return 1 (the first) element with the specific tags and attributes found in the html, even if there are 100s. Like stated in the comments, you want to use `find_all()` of those tags with the specific class. Then you can iterate through those to get each:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
source = requests.get("https://www.11v11.com/teams/arsenal/tab/opposingTeams/opposition/Chelsea/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
games = soup.find_all(class_="result-status")
for game in games:
    print(game.text)
```

**Output:**

```
L
D
W
D
W
...
L
L
D
W
W
```

Answer (score 2):

```
games = soup.find_all(class_="result-status")
```

The result will be in list of elements with class "result-status".
You can iterate over and extract data

Comment: Yes, the output was in a list, thank you.